# How to populate a picklist field with its label value instead of API value in apex

Tags: apex, picklist, describesobject

I have configured the picklist values like this.
[image]

If I want to populate the picklist field by label value we need to query object schema and iterate to find [API value](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/keeping-picklist-integrations-safe-using-api-names).

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.PicklistField__c.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> values = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
Map<String, String> labelAPIMap = new Map<String, String>();
for(Schema.PicklistEntry v : values) {
     Create Label API MAP (label value, API Name)
}
Account a = new Account();
a.Name = 'Jaydeep';
a.PicklistField = labelAPIMap.get('labelName');

insert a;
```

Is there any direct way to populate the picklist field using label value without creating picklist value Map in apex?

Comment: it sounds like [X-Y](https://xyproblem.info/) problem. Can you please add the context and more details?

Comment: Hi @OleksandrBerehovskyi, I have updated the question.